# Field name conventions in GIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

What is the recognised naming style for field names in Geographic Information Systems (i.e. in shapefile layers)? Most datasets that I use with QGIS seem to use all caps (e.g. 'FIELDNAME') and underscores for word breaks ('FIELD_NAME'), but these have mostly been created with ArcGIS, so I was wondering whether this was because of a limitation to upper case in that package. What about other options, such as 'Fieldname', 'FieldName', 'Field-name'? Are any of these okay, or frowned upon?

What about conventions for filenames?

Answer (score 1):

There are no general conventions as far as I am aware of, there are only limitations or defaults of software.  So for example, if you use PostgreSQL, by default all field names will be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

As said by nmtoken in his answer there are no strict rule regarding the case but some storage format may have more or less strict limitation : 10 character maximum for shapefile field name, only using alphanumeric character or underscore, not using some reserved word or not starting with a number for exemple (there may be other and some GIS software will happily read some file that break all these rule but have problem when you try to effectively use the data).

As data are often exchanged in a different format than the storage format it's probably a good habit to respect as much rule as you can (receiving an exported shapefile with field name like "DATA_FOR_Y", "DATA_FOR_1", "DATA_FOR_2" when you expect "DATA_FOR_YEAR_2015", "DATA_FOR_YEAR_2010", "DATA_FOR_YEAR_2020" is not very convenient for exemple)

The habit to use all uppercase probably come from these limitations (the 10 character max make you create codelike fieldname that may be easier to read in uppercase and uppercase make more difficult to use forbidden character like éàèùç...)

As far as I know ESRI FGBD will happily let you use any case you want for file name (upper, lower or mixed) but wont accept space, special character or reserved field name for exemple.

Comment: Many thanks, very helpful.